# mysql json_extract function

Tags: mysql, json

my mysql column named `json`:

```
{"myarray":[ { "users":"82,191", type":"3" } ]}
```

this is above table column `json` i want to find user with id 191. 82 working fine. but 191 not found.

my sql query is:

```
SELECT id 
FROM tablename 
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(json, CONCAT('$.myarray[0].users') ) IN (82) --this is working

SELECT id 
FROM tablename 
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(json, CONCAT('$.myarray[0].users') ) IN (191) --but this is not working. nothing fetched. empty results.
```

how can i fetch results if json has also 191 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[JSON_EXTRACT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html) in your case returns quoted string `"82,191"` so for search you can use combination [JSON_UNQUOTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html) with [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) like:

```
SELECT id 
  FROM tablename 
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(82, JSON_UNQUOTE(
    JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$.myarray[0].users')
  )) > 0;
```

Or Directly ( without Unquoting )

```
SELECT id 
  FROM tablename 
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET (82, json ->> '$.myarray[0].users')
```